# Detection of duplicates in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have dealt with serial numbers that are stored as text in the cells because sometimes the serial numbers have letters. I encountered something that I don't quite understand about **duplicate detection**. Microsoft Excel, at least from Excel 2007, provides a way to highlight duplicate cells. My first thought was that it checks if the cells have exactly the same value, but yet I faced this example:

[image: Values]

These cells are stored as 'Text' values, but obviously don't have the same values, and yet are flagged as duplicates. I encountered this both on Excel 2007 and Excel 2010.

Here are few thoughts I had on this:

- *Perhaps the algorithm checks only X first characters (15 first characters?), or Y positions of the text?*

  So I tried various things and ended up concluding it was not the case
- *Maybe the Text type was bugged*

  I tried a bunch of types for values and it didn't seem to work.
- *Maybe the cell misrecognized the data*

  I tried adding an apostrophe before, and it didn't work.
- *Maybe I misunderstand the definition of duplicate*

Why did these cells got flagged as duplicates?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Share example file...

Comment: Can you include a screencap of the settings for the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce the problem in Excel 2016. It appear when you try to use the "Duplicate Values" option in conditional formatting or *some* formulas (ex: `COUNTIF(A$1:A$5,A1)>1`).

The problem disappears the moment you add a letter to the sequence, suggesting even though it's formatted as text, at one point Excel interprets the number sequence as a number and since you have more than 15 digits, does some rounding to do the comparison.

Here is a formula for the conditional format that works on strictly numeric sequences, no matter their length:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A$5=A1))>1
```

Comment: Wow, interesting. So it is a bug of Excel? So I use your formula as the condition to flag the duplicate right? Thank you for your answer.